# Search statistics on Searchkick

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, statistics, searchkick

I have a project on rais with searchkick and I was trying to find out if there is a way to get what people are searching the most on my site.

Is this possible with searchkick and elasticsearch?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes, it is possible.**

Running together with `searchkick` you can use [searchjoy](https://github.com/ankane/searchjoy) gem. With searchjoy you can view and monitor the performance of your **top searches**.

If you don't want to use `searchjoy`, you can use searchkick's conversion feature. I think is not what you really want because with only conversions you will not be able to see the top searches. More information about searchkick conversions you can find at the [docs](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#keep-getting-better).

Comment: Looks, real nice. Sadly I'm not on that project anymore and can't test it right now, but it looks like the answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using the ["conversions" feature](https://github.com/ankane/searchkick#keep-getting-better) from searchkick. You can use that to persist queries as listed in the readme. I haven't tried it myself, but I would thisnk Redis would be a good choice to persist these data.